# Launching a JavaFx 2.0 application via JNLP throws an exception

Tags: java, deployment, javafx, jnlp

How can I start a JavaFx 2.0 application via WebStart?

I use NetBeans (version 7.1 RC1) to implement a JavaFx 2.0 application, it is startable via click on the jar file. Now I want to get it started via WebStart also. In this forum and other descriptions I found several hints just to use NetBeans for this task, as NetBeans creates all necessary files.

Indeed NetBeans creates a JNLP HTML file and a HTML file, referring this JNLP, both in the projects dist folder. I can load the HTML file in a browser; it shows a header line and a Launch button. Clicking the Launch button invokes the expected dialog "Open launch.jnlp", but click OK there causes an exception dialog, showing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application launch error
   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:104)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:140)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:27)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:97)
...
```

Do I need certain settings in the project properties in NetBeans? Or do I need to sign the jar file or the jnlp file? I also tried that, but also then the same exception occurred.

Currently I do not yet have a website containing the application; I assume for first testing I can invoke the jnlp file which is on my own hard disk, is that right?

What can be the reason for the exception? And what do I have to do to get the WebStart working?

Comment: When you say you are seeing the HTML in a browser, do you mean that you have a web container set-up and are accessing it through `localhost`, or do you mean using a file URI like `file:///C:/dev/ourapp.htm`?  I expect the latter would fail.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I used the URI file:///E:filename.  

Now I found a deploy description: [link]http://glassfish.java.net/docs/3.1/quick-start-guide.pdf[liml].

So I started glassfish, invoked `code`asadmin deploy myApp.jar`code` and typed the URI `code`http://localhost:8080/myApp`code`, what also starts a WebStart, but then throws the exception:
`code`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/___JWSappclient/___app/myApp/myAppClient.jar`code`.

The guide describes to deploy a war file, but NetBeans does not create that. Do I need a war?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have javafx runtime version different from sdk version. Try to uninstall JavaFX runtime (from Control Panel->Uninstall Program) and install using exe file in you JavaFX SDK folder (or download one from javafx.com)

P.S.: you don't have to deploy anything to run regular javafx program using jnlp or browser plugin.